# How to query a query result in Saxon xquery

Tags: java, xpath, saxon

I'm trying to do a basic thing in Saxon HE 9.7 with xquery. I have an xquery that returns a set of elements. Then I want to query each element separately. But I can't seem to figure out how to do a query on just that element. I thought `setContextItem()` would do the trick, but that doesn't work.

I've created a simple example that illustrates my problem. I am looping over `<element>` and then I want to retrieve the `<name>` for each element. But my query returns nothing, because it is actually querying the complete xml, not just the element. If I change the inner query to `//name` it returns all name tags in the document.

File data/example.xml:

```
<root>
    <element>
        <name>1</name>
    </element>
    <element>
        <name>2</name>
    </element>
</root>
```

Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SaxonApiException
{
    Processor proc = new Processor(false);
    XPathCompiler xpath = proc.newXPathCompiler();
    DocumentBuilder builder = proc.newDocumentBuilder();
    XdmNode rootNode = builder.build(new File("data/example.xml"));
    String xquery = "/root/element";
    XPathSelector selector = xpath.compile(xquery).load();
    selector.setContextItem(rootNode);
    for (XdmItem item : selector)
    {
        xquery = "/element/name";
        XPathSelector selector2 = xpath.compile(xquery).load();
        selector2.setContextItem(item);
        System.out.println("item=" + item);
        if (selector2.iterator().hasNext())
            System.out.println("name=" + selector2.iterator().next());
        else
            System.out.println("Not found");
    }
}
```

My Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
    <artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId>
    <version>9.7.0-4</version>
</dependency>
```

Result:

```
item=<element>
        <name>1</name>
    </element>
Not found
item=<element>
        <name>2</name>
    </element>
Not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XPath, `/` at the beginning always references the document node. If you want your XPath (the one inside the loop) to respect context element, try to make it starts with a full-stop (`.`) :

```
xquery = "./name";
```

Or just remove the `/` completely * :

```
xquery = "name";
```

*) this will work for your case because `child::` is the default axis which will be used if none is explicitly mentioned